# How to return an aggregate query in an Apollo resolver (Meteor/Apollo/Graphql)?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, graphql, mongodb-query, apollo

I'm trying to run a query with an aggregate in Meteor and I've not been able to figure out how to return an aggregation query.

In my GraphQL schema:

```
type UserRelation {
    date: String!
    userID: String!
}
type UserData {
    userID: String!
    description: String!
    friends_list: [UserRelation]!
}
extend type Query {
    getFriends(userID: String!, friendID: String): [UserRelation]
}
```

In my resolvers.js:

```
import UserData from "./userData";
export default {
    Query: {
        getFriends(obj, args, context) {
            if (args.friendID) return UserData.rawCollection().aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        _id: 'cuS7KebEQDRv2iFpJ'    
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: '$friends_list'
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        'friends_list._id': '8GW4gjwWhkEexfndd'
                    }
                }
            ]);
            return UserData.findOne({ userID: args.userID }, {fields: {_id: 0,  friends_list: 1 }}).friends_list;
        }
    }
}
```

In this hardcoded example, I have the following document in my database:
[image: Example 1]

And I want to return the entire document with ONLY the user with a matched _id and whose friends_list has another user with the second matched _id. So this way I can return the entire document with only that 1 element in the friends_list array instead of all other elements as well.

Now this query works fine in Robo3T (a MongoDB GUI), but there's an issue with the return statement when I run it in Graphiql as an error is thrown which states:
`"Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field \"Query.getFriends\"."` When I log that statement, I see a [Mongo AggregationCursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#aggregate). But I'm not sure how I should "convert" this to a type that the resolver can return properly.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: findOne doesn't return an array?

Comment: No this isn't for findOne, that part works fine. findOne returns the entire friends_list array of a specific user. findOne is only run if the optional friendID argument is not specified, in which case I return the entire friends_list array.

Comment: just log data before return, check structure, compare to expected

Comment: I did that, and it shows an AggregationCursor. I was not sure how to "convert" that into something proper but I think as per my answer below I may (?) have figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I actually figured it out because I need to test it more, but this is working so far, in my resolvers.js I have:

```
import UserData from "./userData";
async function getFriend(userID, friendID) {
    return UserData.rawCollection().aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                _id: userID    
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$friends_list'
        },
        {
            $match: {
                'friends_list._id': friendID
            }
        }
    ]).toArray();
}

export default {
    Query: {
        async getFriends(obj, args, context) {
            if (args.friendID){
                const result = await getFriend(args.userID, args.friendID);
                return result[0].friends_list;
            }
            return UserData.findOne({ userID: args.userID }, {fields: {_id: 0,  friends_list: 1 }}).friends_list;
        }
    }
}
```

By making it async I was able to get this done. Not sure what implications this has, but so far it works. If anyone is able to review this and give some critique to improve this it would be sincerely appreciated, as any information about this has been excruciatingly difficult to find, as I have not seen any use-cases of this so far.